# How TCP and SSL/TLS interacts?

Tags: ssl, tcp, cryptography, tls1.2, pki

SSL/TLS runs over the TCP layer. Suppose TCP connection is terminated before SSL/TLS session was closed. How would SSL/TLS get to know about this ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

A TLS session is mostly independent from the underlying TCP connections.

For example you can have multiple TCP connections all using the same TLS session and these can coexist even in parallel. This is actually used in practice, for example with web browsers. It is even required in some implementations of FTPS where the control and data connections (different TCP connections) are expected to (re)use the same TLS session. Note that the session does not simply gets continued inside another TCP connection - there is still a TLS handshake required to start the "continuation" of a session, but only an abbreviated handshake.

Similar you can have multiple TLS sessions inside a single TCP connection but only after each other: initiate one TLS session, shutdown it, initiate the next etc. While this is not commonly used it is actually not uncommon that the TLS session does only start after some plain data has been transferred (`STARTTLS` in SMTP, `AUTH TLS` in FTPS) or that TLS gets shutdown and then more data are transferred in plain (`CCC` in FTPS).

> How would SSL/TLS get to know about this ?

The exact details depend on the TLS stack and the API provided by this stack. But usually if the underlying TCP connection is closed this is somehow signaled to the TLS stack. For example with OpenSSL a `SSL_read` will return a value of equal or less than 0 and you need to call `SSL_get_error` to get more details on what happened. And again, a TCP close does not implicitly invalidate the TLS session.

Comment: TLS sessions are invalidated regularly during the uptime of a TLS server, e.g. HTTPS. This can cause exactly what you describe in the last paragraph, and it is rather common.

Comment: @EJP: what I describe in the last paragraph is an explicit shutdown of the TLS connection inside an existing TCP connection and then maybe some time later another TLS handshake inside the same TCP connection. I don't think this has anything to do with the invalidating of cached TLS session information inside the server. These cached session information are only needed on session resume and invalidating these information does not cause the existing TLS session to be closed and a new one created.

Comment: @EJP: it might be that we are talking about different things with the same name: I mean the TLS session as it is used to transfer data inside the TCP connection. You might mean the TLS session structure (like openssl `SSL_SESSION`) which is used to store information about a session which existed once, might exist currently or might exist again in the future.

Comment: There is no difference between 'TLS session' and 'TLS session', and there is no such thing as 'explicit shutdown of a TLS session'. There is only invalidation, which prevents further resumption, which in turn means that a new handshake has to create a new session.

Answer (score 0):

> SSL/TLS runs over the TCP layer.

Correct.

> Suppose TCP connection is terminated before SSL/TLS session was closed.

Then (a) the TCP connection has ended, and (b ) the SSL/TLS session persists.

> How would SSL/TLS get to know about this?

It doesn't need to know about this. It only needs to know about the end of the TCP connection, which is signalled by the TLS `close_notify` message, and the end of the session, which happens when it is invalidated. TLS sessions can long outlive TCP connections, and *vice versa.*

Comment: The end of the TCP connection is not signaled by a `close_notify`. A `close_notify` is  explicitly send by the peer on SSL shutdown (e.g. using OpenSSL `SSL_shutdown`). Such SSL shutdown (and thus sending of `close_notify`) does not need to be done only when the TCP connection gets closed: for example in FTPS it is not uncommon to shutdown SSL after authentication and continue with a plain TCP control connection. Similar a close of the underlying TCP connection will not magically create a `close_notify` from nowhere, the `close_notify` needs to be send while the TCP connection is still open.

Answer (score -1):

There is a heartbeat protocol that is used by SSL/TLS to check that the connection is still alive or not. So for a heartbeat request a closed connection will response negative. Hence SSL/TLS will know that TCP connection is closed.

Comment: There is no heartbeat protocol that is used by either SSL or TLS defined in RFC 2246 or its successors. If you believe otherwise please provide a citation to support your assertion.